# How to correctly wrap a one time jquery call inside an AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive which transforms

```
<a caracteristic="caracteristics.strength"></a>
```

into a more elaborated tag with correct values :

template.html

```
<a ng-href="regles#{{ caracteristic.name | lowercase }}" class="ui mini {{ caracteristic.color }} label" data-title="{{ caracteristic.name }}" data-content="{{ caracteristic.description }}">{{ caracteristic.name | uppercase}}</a>
```

Here is the directive :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('caracteristic', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'components/caracteristic/caracteristic.html',
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                caracteristic: '='
            },
            replace: true,
            link: function() {
                $('.mini.label').popup({
                    transition : 'fade up',
                    variation : "large"
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

So basically my model won't change and if i render two a tag with my directive the $(...).popup will be called twice.

How can I make it load only once ?

PS : i'm totally new in angularJS, too novice to convert this jQuery plugin into native Angular for now. If i'm totally wrong, enlight me ! ;)

Comment: You're directive is working exactly as it should. Angular directives provide some functionality (in your case invoking transforming the `a` tag and invoking `$('.mini.label').popup()`) for every instance in which they are used. If use it twice, the expected behavior is that you will get your popup twice.

Comment: @JME : It is working, yes but `$('.mini.label').popup()` could be loaded once and it would do the same only if the dom is ready. Isn't it hard to launch and relaunch and rerelaunch this query call when it's only needed once ?

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my point clearly. Since Angular directives provide some repeatable functionality for every instance in which they are used, and that apparently is not your intent, then I suppose my point is that you should not be using a directive in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The popup code seems completely separate from your caracteristic directive, so I'm not sure why you'd put it there in the first place. You should be looking to create a popup directive:

```
app.directive('popup', function() {
    return function (scope, elem) {
        elem.popup({
            transition : 'fade up',
            variation : "large"
        });
    };
});
```

then attach that to the element you want to popup:

```
<div popup class="mini label"></div>
```